# Customisable Tabbed Content

Tags: nodes, javascript

Hi guys i'm trying to create a restaurant menu like below:
[image]

I've created a 'Venues' content type, in which it contain the usual Title, Description, Image and another Taxonomy field for Category (Type of Restaurant).

At the bottom i'd like a tabbed menu like the image above. Just not sure how I can go about creating it. Ideally i'd like:

- Let the user create up to 4 or 5 tabs
- Each tab to have a title (Which is displayed in the section and on the tabs)
- Each tab to have X amount of items (Name, Description Price)

Not sure if there's a module that helps with this or if I should use Views somehow or what fields I should add to the content type. Totally baffled.

In my static HTML prototype, I used jQuery UI to build the tabs, will I need to use that again here or again, is there a module that can help with that?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the [jQuery Tabs Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_jquery_tabs) module for this.

> jQuery Tabs Field module allows you to create jQuery Tabs field. Using this you can add upto 7 tabs with tab title and tab body in a node. After saving node, the module will display all these 7 tabs as jQuery tabs.